Why adding a read replica creates a "Writer instance" on AWS?
I've just created an Aurora Read Replica for my RDS database and it shows up as "Writer instance" in the list. That doesn't make much sense to me - any idea if I somehow need to configure it differently?
My use case is that I want a read-only replica so I don't want any writes to potentially reach the instance (or if they do, they should fail).
To be clear, the option I selected was this one:

And this is what I got:


To answer my own questions, when clicking on the "Replica cluster", there are two endpoints: one of them is the "Write instance" endpoint, and the other is a read-only endpoint (with "ro" in the name).
So the whole thing is poorly named I guess - you don't just create a "read replica", you create a cluster with a writer instance. And that also includes a read-only endpoint.
